# extract contents of several parenthesis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, text-processing

Given a text file as shown below, how can I extract the contents using MATLAB? The number of parenthesis is equal to #Pins (column 3). I used **textscan** and **regexp** but was unsuccessful.

```
Net  Name       #Pins   Driver      Recvs

0    o_6_       2   (   1,  13) (   0,   0)

1    i_9_       5   (   6,   1) (   2,   0) (  21,   1) (  28,   2) (  38,   3) 

2    n_n22      4   (  25,  13) (   2,   1) (   3,   7) (  22,   0)

3    [286]      2   (   8,  13) (   1,   2)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @rayryeng for each line, numbers in parenthesis.(in an array structure) for example for net 0, [1,13] and [0,0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fgetl](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to read line by line the input file within a loop.

Then you can use [strtok](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html?searchHighlight=strtok) to parse the current line, using `(` as `delimiter` within a loop.

Next step is to replace `,` and `)` in each token and convert the resulting string into an array with [str2num](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html?searchHighlight=str2num).

In the question you did not specify how to store the data extracted, so two possibilities could be:

- store the data into a struct, each field is named according to the ID of the "Net" (the names of the field can be [created dynamically](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)
- store the data into a cellarray

This approach has been iimplemented in the following code; the comments in the code should explain the different steps.

```
% Open the input file
fp_in=fopen('read_bra.txt','rt');
% Initiaize the output cellarray
data_cell{1}=[];
% Initialize the counter for the cellarray
cnt=0;
% Loop to read the input file, line by line
while 1
   % Read a line
   tline = fgetl(fp_in);
   % If the last line of the file has been read
   if(~ischar(tline))
      % Close the input file and exit from the (infinite) loop
      fclose(fp_in);
      break
   end
   % split current line into tokens
   [token, remain]=strtok(tline,'(');
   % The "once" flag:
   %    once == 1: read the ID of the "Net"
   %               reset the temporary matrix "v"
   %               Initialize the output sctructure field
   %               Increment the counter for the cellarray
   %    once == 2: current line is valid (is not empty, and contains data
   %               store the data in the output struct
   %               store the data in the output cellarray
   once=1;
   while(~isempty(remain))
      if(once == 1)
         net_n=sscanf(tline,'%d');
         once=2;
         v=[];
         data_str.(['net_' num2str(net_n)])=[];
         cnt=cnt+1;
      end
      % Split the line wrt "("
      [token, remain]=strtok(remain,'(');
      % Store the data from the current token in the temporary matrix
      v=[v;str2num(strrep(strrep(token,',',''),')',''))];
   end
   % Once all the data of the current line have been extracted
   if(once == 2)
      % Store the data in the output struct
      data_str.(['net_' num2str(net_n)])=v;
      % Store the data in the output cellarray
      data_cell{cnt}=v;
      % Resert the "once" flag
      once=0;
   end
end
```

Given the input file you've posted, the output is:

```
data_str = 

    net_0: [2x2 double]
    net_1: [5x2 double]
    net_2: [4x2 double]
    net_3: [2x2 double]


data_str.net_0
ans =
     1    13
     0     0
data_str.net_1
ans =
     6     1
     2     0
    21     1
    28     2
    38     3
data_str.net_2
ans =
    25    13
     2     1
     3     7
    22     0
data_str.net_3
ans =
     8    13
     1     2


data_cell = 

    [2x2 double]    [5x2 double]    [4x2 double]    [2x2 double]

data_cell{1}
ans =
     1    13
     0     0
data_cell{2}
ans =
     6     1
     2     0
    21     1
    28     2
    38     3
data_cell{3}
ans =
    25    13
     2     1
     3     7
    22     0
data_cell{4}
ans =
     8    13
     1     2
```